# How to translate alignof to Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

How can I translate `alignof` operator to Delphi? I need it to translate

```
#define INET_IS_ALIGNED(Pointer, Type) \
   (((ULONG_PTR)Pointer & (__builtin_alignof(Type)-1)) == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I translate alignof operator to Delphi?

You cannot. There is no equivalent.

Comment: There is this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Align_fields_(Delphi) but I'm not sure there's a way you can check this in compiler directives.

Comment: @Stijn Each type has its own alignment. The compiler offers no way to retrieve that. The compiler knows, but won't tell you. An offsetof and alignof would be useful, to go with sizeof.